# How to get another location IP Address in Android?

Tags: android, networking, lte

---

**City1** : PG-W1 (IP Pool 1.1.0.0/16)

**City2** : PG-W2 (IP Pool 2.2.0.0/16)

---

If I use Android(PDN Address : 1.1.1.1) in City1,

How do I get the IP(2.2.2.2) of the City2? (Without moving)

I tried to find the associated document but failed.. :_(

Comment: http://www.netmanias.com/en/?m=view&id=techdocs&no=7257

Comment: Can you explain what your question is here - it is not entirely clear?